# How to insert reverse relation via optimized query

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table (sample given below) where I have relations like cid_i --> cid_j with some value Val

I want to insert reverse relation cid_j--> cid_i with same val that was  cid_i --> cid_j.

This is a business requirement and I have to provide that table in the same manner only. I have tried and below is my query.I don't want duplicates so I used a correlated subquery to resolve this.

Is there any optimized way to do this.

Please suggest.

```
declare @tbl table (cid_i int, cid_j int, val float )

insert into @tbl (cid_i , cid_j ,val)
values(1,2,0.5),(1,3,0.6),(2,1,0.5) 



insert into @tbl  (cid_i , cid_j ,val)
select cid_j , cid_i,val   from @tbl a 
where cid_j not in (select cid_i from @tbl b  where b.cid_j=a.cid_i)

select * from @tbl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I would use [`EXCEPT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql) for this:

```
INSERT INTO @tbl (cid_i , cid_j ,val)
SELECT cid_j, cid_i ,val
FROM @tbl t0

EXCEPT 

SELECT cid_i , cid_j ,val
FROM @Tbl
```

However, As pointed out in daniel.shih's answer, keeping these records is redundant, as the opposite relationship can be easily selected using union.

Comment: One side relation already present in table I need to only insert reverse side that is j to i, how the union can be used in this case. I am not able to understand.

Comment: A Union would be used to select both existing and opposite relations, so there really is no need to store opposite relations

Comment: This is a business requirement I need to fill data only.After that, another team would use this I cannot tell them to make query because they might be using some other tool to fetch data.

Comment: And that's why I've shown you a possible way to do it. I know that we don't always have control over business requirements...

Comment: How would a union or except be more optimized than correlated subquery I  have used.

Comment: thanks with regards but you made me confused by saying

"However, As pointed out in daniel.shih's answer, keeping these records is redundant, as the opposite relationship can be easily selected using union."

Comment: I'm not sure they will be more optimized. the query optimizer might create the same execution plan for except and a sub query. using Union will eliminate the need to keep both directions of the relationship, but as you wrote, it's a business requirement you can't change, so it's not relevant

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `UNION` to make it.

The point is

> 1. First select query is `SELECT cid_j,cid_i,val  from @tbl`
> 2. Seconde select query is `SELECT cid_i,cid_j,val  from @tbl`

You may switch your select field,which you want to reverse.

```
DECLARE @tbl table (cid_i int, cid_j int, val float )

INSERT INTO @tbl (cid_i , cid_j ,val)
VALUE(1,2,0.5),(1,3,0.6),(2,1,0.5) 
SELECT cid_j,cid_i,val  from @tbl
UNION 
SELECT cid_i,cid_j,val   from @tbl
```